# Comparing the content of two Google Drive folders

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

Hello people of the internet, this is my first post here so hit me up if I forget any kind of information that could help you help me with this issue.

I am making a Google App Script that is supposed to list all files contained in two different folders in Google Drive and compare them. The first folder is called "archives" and contains a list of pdf files, and the second folder is called "to_compare". In theory, these two folders contain the same files, except the "to_compare" folder which is daily updated with new files. The goal of my script is to spot when the updated files are different from the "archives" files.

Here is my current code, and my issue is that, for some reason that I can't explain, my script goes through my files in a strange order. I thought it was going to iterate inside my folder following my file names, but it seems like it's not the case.

All of the feedback I get from my comparison is stored in a spreadsheet summing up the file name, file size and date when a change have been detected.

Do you know a way where I can compare my files by their name and not by their order in my folder? Thank you if you took some of your spare time to help me with this.

```js
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var folder1 = DriveApp.getFolderById('1bClALidaF9pYgENndpmD_mpvqgcD_tPx'); // archives
  var folder2 = DriveApp.getFolderById('1IediXKEC_vJJSIyObOPwrpqEbaDPuRCa'); // to_compare
  var list1 = [];
  var list2 = [];
  var list3 = [];
  var list4 = [];
  var files1 = folder1.getFiles();
  var files2 = folder2.getFiles();
  var now = new Date();
  while (files1.hasNext() && files2.hasNext()){
    var file1 = files1.next();
    var file2 = files2.next();
    list1.push([file1.getName()]);
    list2.push([file2.getName()]);
    list3.push([file1.getSize()]);
    list4.push([file2.getSize()]);
  }
  sh.getRange(1,2,list1.length,1).setValues(list1);
  sh.getRange(1,3,list2.length,1).setValues(list2);
  sh.getRange(1,4,list3.length,1).setValues(list3);
  sh.getRange(1,5,list4.length,1).setValues(list4);
  const equals = (a, b) => JSON.stringify(a) === JSON.stringify(b);

  var i=0;
  //gathering values of filesize 1 & 2 and comparing them
  for (i > 0;i<list1.length;i++){
    var a= sh.getRange("d1:d48").getValues(); 
    var b= sh.getRange("e1:e48").getValues();
    
    
    if(!equals(a, b)) //if the filesize is not the same, then...
    {
      sh.getRange(i+1,6).setBackground("red")
      sh.getRange(i+1,6).setValue("something has changed here...")
      sh.getRange(i+1,7).setValue(now)
      //++sending an email to team
    }
    else{
      sh.getRange(i+1, 6).setBackground("green")
      sh.getRange(i+1, 6).setValue("everything's ok!")
    }
  }
```

Comment: I think the iterator puts them in the order they were created but I'm not totally sure about that.  You can store you data from the iterator in an array and then sort the array by name and then do you comparison.  In Google files can have the same name but they always have unique ids

Comment: thank you @Cooper for your answer! you were right about the way files are ordered in my folders. they are stored in order of download. So I decided to order alphabetically my list of files in my `list1` and `list2`. But how do I keep this order in my `list3` and `list4` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your putting them in four adjacent columns why not this:

```
list1.push([file1.getName(),file2.getName(),file1.getSize(),file2.getSize()]);
```

then

```
sh.getRange(1,2,list1.length,4).setValues(list1);
```

You can sort them as a range in the spreadsheet or sort them via .sort() method with compare function in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you again for your answer. But after aplying the `.sort()` method, it seems like only the archive folder is being sorted...

Here is my code now:

````
function file_comparison(){
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var folder1 = DriveApp.getFolderById('ID1'); // archives
  var folder2 = DriveApp.getFolderById('ID2'); // to_compare
  var list1 = [];
  var files1 = folder1.getFiles();
  var files2 = folder2.getFiles();
  var now = new Date();
  while (files1.hasNext() && files2.hasNext()){
    var file1 = files1.next();
    file1.setDescription("archives")
    var file2 = files2.next();
    file2.setDescription("to_compare")
    list1.push([file1.getName(),file2.getName(),file1.getSize(),file2.getSize()]);
    list1.sort();
  }
  sh.getRange(1,2,list1.length,4).setValues(list1);
  const equals = (a, b) => JSON.stringify(a) === JSON.stringify(b);

  var i=0;
  //gathering values of filesize 1 & 2 and comparing them
  for (i > 0;i<list1.length;i++){
    var a= sh.getRange("d1:d48").getValues(); 
    var b= sh.getRange("e1:e48").getValues();
    
    
    if(!equals(a, b)) //if the filesize is not the same, then...
    {
      //alert
    }
    else{
     //else...
    }
  }```
````

Comment: I also said that you would need to provide a compare function to the sort.

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for: a way to compare my two folders file by file. I heard about the `.getFilesByName()` method, but it is only usefull on folders in order to get all the files stored inside. Any idea?

Comment: I finaly managed to sort my files by spliting my list in two separated lists, each of them containing the file name and the file size, both sorted individually.  Thank you again @Cooper for your time and for your tips :)

Comment: The basic how to of what I was talking about is described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) Pay particular attention to the part that talks about what you need to return from the compare function.  The would allow you to sort arrays of objects based upon any properties of the object.

Comment: the solution I found was a little bit easier. In my case the information that i was trying to sort was only the name of my files. So here is what i did:
`list1.push([file1.getName(),file1.getSize()]);
    list1.sort();
    list2.push([file2.getName(),file2.getSize()])
    list2.sort();`

Comment: One of the problems with sort method is that the default method sorts as a string but what does it mean to sort a row of columns as a string. I'm not sure what that even does.